# How to do A or B not C in new nav tag filters?

Tags: support, new-nav, tag-search

I'm trying to set up a tab showing latest questions tagged with A or B but not C, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get this to work?

Some things I've tried:

- `[A] [B] not [C]` shows everything (presumably it assumed "`or not [C]`").
- `[A] [B] and not [C]` is exactly the same as `[A] or [B]`.

And sometimes, while trying to edit the query, the results lock up with no results and won't update any more - but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I don't think that is possible

Comment: @rene then this becomes a [tag:feature-request]